# Eliminate repeated values from a Table after database extraction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im coding in PHP and SQL after finishing the web site I realize that in my bloucles, that take their info from the database I have repeated values,

Here you will understand better:

I have this code:

```
<?php
    
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","motorsportgeneral") or die("1");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars ";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        
        if($result)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
    
    ?>
    
    <?php echo $row['model'] ?>
    
    
    <?php
    
            }
        }
    
    ?>
```

If in the rows of my table I have 2 repeated values the server will show this:

> Hello1
>
> Hello2
>
> Hello1
>
> Hello2

**How can I eliminate this repeated values in my list, with out touching the table?**

Thanks, I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT model FROM cars
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT model FROM cars
```

That should do the trick, if I understand correctly.